# Big Query Performance - Is there a way to partition by multiple dimentions (Date and customer) ? One Big table Vs 400 Tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

We are evaluating cloud warehouse options to build a analytics solution. We need to provide trend analysis per day, per customer across many customers (400+), ratio of queries for across these two dimensions are equal. My initial thought is to create Date partitioned table one per customer, so for queries per customer I limit the scan to one particular day and for queries across all customer I use table wildcard feature.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to partition by Date and customer, so I can store all data in one table and still limit data scan volume?
2. If ans to #1 is no, What is the performance impact of querying across 400 tables Vs one table (same amount of data)

Answer (score 1):

1. Hash partitioning and partitioning by specific fields in a table are not supported yet, so this is not feasible now.
2. If you query the 400 tables using wildcards and filter customers using _TABLESUFFIX, the query will only read the matching tables and you'll only be charged for those tables; if you query one table then you can filter dates using _PARTITIONTIME and you'll only be charged for the matching partitions. Performance wise less metadata is read if you query one table, but that shouldn't be much for 400 tables.

Comment: Thank You, I notice that I can not use _partitiontime and _tablesuffix in the same query in standard SQL to scan only needed partition in matching tables. however I can use TABLE_QUERY with table_id filter along with   _partitiontime this helps limit scanned data because I can only read needed partitions from matching tables.